# Is there any possible memory leak in this code?

Tags: c++

Josuttis shows an example about a possible allocator use (chapter 15):

```
void vector<T,Allocator>::reserve(size_type size)
{
    //allocate new memory for size elements
    T* newmem = alloc.allocate (size);
    //copy old elements into new memory
    uninitialized_copy(elems,elems+numElems,newmem);
```

What happens if uninitialized_copy fails? Is there any memory leak or is `::operator delete` magically called (see the comment in the code below):

```
  template <class InputIter, class ForwIter>
  ForwIter uninitialized_copy(lnputIter beg, InputIter end, ForwIter dest)
  {
    typedef typename iterator_traits<ForwIter>::value_type VT;
    ForwIter save(dest);
    try {
       for (; beg!=end; ++beg,++dest) {
           new (static_cast<void*>(&*dest))VT(*beg);
       }
       return dest;
    }
    catch (...) {
       for (; save!=dest; ++save) {
           save->~VT();
       }
       throw; // will ::operator delete() be called to free the previously allocated memory?
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, your code *will* leak memory, and the `uninitialized_copy` has to be contained in a `try`/`catch` block itself. The whole purpose of rethrowing the exception inside the copy function is so that it is possible to signal atomically that the copy operation failed, so that the ambient code can perform its own cleanup:

```
T* newmem = alloc.allocate (size);
try { /* copy, reassign pointer, free previous  */ }
catch (...) { alloc.deallocate(newmem); throw; }
```

Comment: Assuming C++11, I think I'd use a `unique_ptr` here rather than `try/catch`, but that's just me.

Comment: @ildjarn: A unique-pointer to *what*? We're setting up a sequence of consecutive `T` objects constructed in-place here. A `unique_ptr<void>` perhaps?

Comment: A `unique_ptr<T*>` with a custom deleter; is RAII not more sensible than `try/catch`?

Comment: @ildjarn: it feels more cumbersome to me, since you'd essentially need a no-op deleter, and then you'd have to `release` the pointer upon success... since we're *implementing* the actual allocation here, the explicit `try`/`catch` feels a lot more straight-forward to me... anyway, that's just opinion.

Comment: Every time someone uses `try/catch` to handle resources, God kills a kitten. Every one loves kittens, pleas use RAII for the sake of little kittens

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Naw, I think try-catch is superior here. I don't want to build up scaffolding when a step-stool will do. (That said, if I were implementing the stdlib myself I *might* make a utility for it, but I'd have to be doing this try-catch block a ton, yet only `vector` comes to mind.)

Comment: Though what we all agree on is the middle ground, built-in RAII generators without the clumsy manual code generation, like D has: `T* newmem = alloc.allocate(size);` followed by: `scope(failure) alloc.deallocate(newmem);` Done and done, no try-catch's, no manually-written wrappers.

Comment: @GManNickG this particular problem is more complex that what I thought. At the end the answer seems to be (if I am not wrong) that for the code to be exception safe you cannot un `uninitialized_copy`. If the nth copy constructor fails, you want to destroy the (n-1) first elements already copied, but by using an algorithm you have given up that possibility (you cannot know N  by the time the exception comes by). The solution would be a hand tailored algorithm that is able to manage that, the alternatives are still the same: either a try/catch, or building a RAII object to manage the loop.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I don't know why, but that comment flew way over my head. What do you mean? Uninitializing already-initialized elements during the loop is already handled by the algorithm.

Comment: @GManNickG: Basically that the allocated block is not the only resource. If any copy constructor throws in the call to `uninitialized_copy` the algorithm will let the exception flow to the caller. The problem now is that some of the constructors may have completed before the exception was thrown, but the caller cannot possibly know how many, so it does not know how many destructors need to be called. I am starting to think that `uninitialized_copy` is *broken* (in the sense that other than for types with `nothrow()` copy constructors, it leads to undefined behavior)...

Comment: ...neither a `try/catch` nor any short of RAII can provide the caller with enough information to release the appropriate number of resources, all hope is lost just because we called an algorithm... I think this is the first algorithm that I would have to recommend not to use in the general case!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: "The problem now is that some of the constructors may have completed before the exception was thrown, but the caller cannot possibly know how many, so it does not know how many destructors need to be called." We don't have to call any, `uninitialized_copy` is require to destruct already-constructed elements in the case of an exception.

Comment: @GManNickG: Oh, you are right I went straight to 20.6.12.2 and missed that 20.6.12/1 imposes that requirement on the algorithms. At this point most of my previous comments make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Ha, it's alright. To be fair, I find it a bit underspecified. It says it has "no effects", yet my copy-constructor may have effects (copy-elison doesn't apply here), so a literal interpretation means the compiler has to magically know ahead of time that the procedure won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through valgrind too. If it has leaks, Valgrind will likely find them as well.